# How do I fix this datetime error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame full of dates. However, some of them are formatted differently than others. For example, I have one in the following format

```
2010-01-22
```

and I also have one in the following format

```
2010-22-1
```

When I use

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I get the error

```
month must be in 1..12: 2010-22-1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should fix it at the source because good luck figuring out what `2010-11-10` is. Unless you have additional information you're not providing I think this isn't specified well enough to get it _correct_ (Like perhaps you have a Series of dates that _should_ be ordered, despite differing formats)

Comment: @ALollz The data is from an excel file. In the excel file they are of the form m/d/yyy. Is this helpful? In the excel file, the ones that are giving me trouble are in the form 2010-22-1 for example. Is there no way to change this?

Comment: @ALollz What do you mean by, "Like perhaps you have a Series of dates that should be ordered, despite differing formats"?

Comment: @ALollz What I did is concatenate many csv files together. These csv files were organized by month and year. That is, the dates above are in a csv file that contains other dates with 2010 as the year and January as the month. Does this help?

Comment: Add a parse parameter to it.and give it fomat from datetime import datetime
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates=['datetime'], date_parser=dateparse)

Comment: you can use `df['date'].apply(your_function)` and write `your function` which will try to arse `year-month-day` and if it catch error the it will try to parse `year-day-month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df['date'].apply(your_function)` and write `your function` which will try to parse `year-month-day` and if it catch error the it will try to parse `year-day-month`

---

Minimal example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def convert(item):
    #print(item)
    
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%d-%m")
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)

    print('not converted:', item)    
    return item

# --- main --

data = {
    'date': ['2010-01-22','2010-22-01', '2021-11-05'], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)


df['date'] = df['date'].apply(convert)
 
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Result:

```
        date
0  2010-01-22
1  2010-22-01
2  2021-11-05

date    object
dtype: object

Exception: time data '2010-22-01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

        date
0 2010-01-22
1 2010-01-22
2 2021-11-05

date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have more formats then you can use `for`-loop

```
def convert(item):
    #print(item)

    for pattern in ["%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%d-%m"]:    
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(item, pattern)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)

    print('not converted:', item)    
    return item
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks so much.